# Powershell Active Directory Get-ADComputer Input

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm attempting to write a Powershell script that allows me to do the following:

1. Use Get-ADGroupMember to get users that are apart of a specific group
2. Use info from step one in Get-ADUser to get user info in lastname, firstname format
3. Use string from step 2 in Get-ADComputer to search the description field of all computers to find computers that have that string within its description field.

Here is what I was trying (thought it would work in my head):

**Get-ADGroupMember 'Group Name' | Get-ADUser -Properties givenName, sn | select givenName, sn** | *Get-ADComputer -filter 'description -like "$sn,$givenName*"' -property description | select Name*

Bold text works, I know Italics text wouldn't work but thats the format of how I'd think it would work

Let me know if I made any since, definitely a Powershell newbie

TLDR: trying to get Names of users and their computer name's based on a search of specific AD group

Answer (score 1):

At that point in the pipeline, you're no longer directly using the output object of `Get-ADUser` as the input object of `Get-ADComputer`. That's where the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet comes in. It takes a scriptblock that allows you the define the behavior for each item in the pipeline:

```
Get-ADGroupMember 'Group Name' | 
    Get-ADUser -Properties givenName, sn | 
    ForEach-Object -Process {
        $sn = $_.sn
        $givenName = $_.givenName

        Get-ADComputer -Filter 'description -like "$sn,$givenName"' -property description
    } | select Name*
```

Comment: Thanks for that. However, I noticed that I could only get the above to work by manually adding a known value in "$sn,$givenName". For example I know one user in a group, so I put their last name "LastName*". This allowed the command to work by only showing that users computer name. Any thoughts on why it's not excepting the $sn and $givenName?

Comment: @Chris not sure as I didn't actually run the code against AD, but check to make sure your property names are correct.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to dig into this. I added an echo line within the ForEach (echo "$sn, $givenName") and they are printing correctly. Unfortunately, when they're being passed into -like "$sn, $givenName*", (added wildcard just to see if it made a difference) nothing is being found. I'll let you know what if I figure it out. Appreciate the help

Comment: @Chris mind your spacing; the code sample you gave in the question has no space after the comma, in the comment though you do have one, make sure it's correct..?